# How to configure new frame font using custom-set-faces?

Tags: init-file, fonts

I'd like to use a fractional font size throughout Emacs.  I have been able to set my default font size on launch using `custom-set-faces`:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#212121"
    :foreground "#e8e8d3" :inverse-video nil :box nil
    :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal
    :weight normal :height 185 :width normal :foundry "nil" :family "Menlo")))))
```

The above configuration works fine on launch after Emacs finally settles on its default frame size.

However, when I create a new frame, this font is not utilized.  I understand that I can use `default-frame-alist` to configure the new frame font, but `default-frame-alist` uses entirely different configuration data which does not seem to support fractional sizes:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
        '((width . 142)
          (height . 54)
          (font . "-*-Menlo-normal-normal-normal-*-18.5-185-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")))
```

The above configuration does not work as expected -- the fractional portion is ignored and I simply receive a frame with an 18 point font.

Comment: The `custom-set-faces` call *should* affect ll frames rather than just the first, so I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the `default` font is the best way to go, rather than using frame parameters. As you can see, the `font` frame parameter is equivalent only to the `:font` attribute of the default face. It can be any font name your system supports, so you can probably use an xft-style font name as well. The older style of font name that you're using basically pre-dates vector fonts, so it's integers all the way.

I would turn off all of your frame parameter customizations and see if you can get back to having it just work with the `default` font. That's the default behavior, so something must be changing it.